Integrating products of many oscillating functions
I'm working with the circular random matrix ensembles, in particular the circular unitary ensemble (CUE). For unitaries drawn from the CUE with dimension $N$, the distribution of its eigenvalues is known,
$$P(\theta_{1},\cdots,\theta_{N}) \propto \prod_{j<k}|e^{i\theta_{j}}-e^{i\theta_{k}}|^{2} = \prod_{j<k}\left[4\sin\left(\frac{\theta_{j}-\theta_{k}}{2}\right)^{2}\right]$$
Now I want to work in the large $N$ limit, and I have a motivation to compute integrals of the form
$$\int d\vec{\theta} P(\vec{\theta}) f(\vec{\theta})$$
where $\vec{\theta}$ is short-hand for all $N$ variables $\theta_{i}$. My (perhaps incorrect) intuition is that $P(\vec{\theta})$ should be negligible in this limit except on a rather constrained subspace of the $N$-torus spanned by the $\theta_{i}$. I'm wondering if there are any natural integral approximations to invoke in such a situation? I'm familiar with techniques like the method of steepest descent, but because there are a large number of exponentials contributing in this situation I am not sure if this will lead to a manageable reorganization of the problem. Perhaps there are better suited approximations to the product of many oscillating functions?

Should there be $\theta$ rather than $\phi$ in the last term of your first expression?

Yes, thanks! Fixed now.
